# Android Gallery and Adapters

Tags: android, xml, button, gallery

I have images that I want them to be in a gallery using an adapter to select each and it will be drawn using canvas, I watched many tutorials and I made my code, now I don't know where is the wrong I'm making

```
Gallery g;
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

       Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gBitmap);
       imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
       g.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    //selected Bitmap from gallery
       g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
               View v, int position, long id) {
               applyBitmap(position);
           }
       });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       int mGalleryItemBackground;
       private Context mContext;

       private Integer[] mImageIds = {
               R.drawable.first,
               R.drawable.second,
               R.drawable.fifth,
               R.drawable.third,
               R.drawable.fourth,

       public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
           mContext = c;
       }

       public int getCount() {
           return mImageIds.length;
       }

       public Object getItem(int position) {
           return position;
       }

       public long getItemId(int position) {
           return position;
       }

       public View getView(int position,
           View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return iv;
       }
    }

    public static void Bitmap(int position) {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inScaled = true;
        opt.inPurgeable = true;
            opt.inInputShareable = true;
            Bitmap brightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, position, opt);
        iv.setImageBitmap(brightBitmap);


    }
```

I need to get the selected `mImageIds` to use my function called `Bitmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this works for you or not,

But make few changes in your code,

**1. applyFrame(int position)**

This code line should be,

```
Bitmap brightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), position, opt);
```

**2. in getView()**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

    return i;
}
```

**3. setOnItemClickListener()**

```
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
               View v, int position, long id) {
               applyFrame(mImageIds[position]);
           }
       });
```

Try this and let me know what happen... If it works then I will explain you. How??

Comment: Yup, made that and I got an error "mImageIds cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Can you post code of Activity Before `onCreate()` or Post Activity code in link...

Answer (score 0):

you should watch the "[the world of listView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" video and know how to create an adapter for adapterView (gallery extends it) .